pgfplots: Option "axis x line = bottom" ignored AFTER "axis x line = center"

This is about pgfplots.
I use the option axis x line to control the placement of the axis x line and the placement of the xlabel.
Problem is that axis x line = bottom is ignored when used after axis x line = center. Normally, the last option "wins" (= overrides the previous setting) when the an option is used several times.
In my actual use case, axis x line = center is used in a pgfplotsset (= "global" options) where several common options are defined but in one specific diagram I want to override the "global" axis x line option.


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} % Does not seem to matter when I remove this.

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin = 0, 
    xmax = 10,
    ymin = 0, 
    ymax = 10,
    axis y line = left,
    axis x line = center,
    xlabel = {xlabel},
    ylabel = {ylabel},
    title = {(1) As Expected (axis x line = center)},
    ]                               
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin = 0, 
    xmax = 10,
    ymin = 0, 
    ymax = 10,
    axis y line = left,
    axis x line = bottom,
    xlabel = {xlabel},
    ylabel = {ylabel},
    title = {(2) As Expected (axis x line = bottom)},
    ]                               
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin = 0, 
    xmax = 10,
    ymin = 0, 
    ymax = 10,
    axis y line = left,
    axis x line = center,
    axis x line = bottom, % <-- Trying to overwrite line before
    xlabel = {xlabel},
    ylabel = {ylabel},
    title = {(3) NOT As Expected (axis x line = bottom AFTER axis x line = center)},
    ]                               
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}



axis x line=bottom is not ignored, as you can see with ymin=-10 (the line is a the right position). But axis x line = center alter the key every axis  x label. You can reset it to its default value with xlabel absolute after axis x line=center.

Thanks. I cannot test right now, but thanks. Would you consider this a bug?

I'm not an expert. I would say it's not a bug, it's more the way axis x line is implemented. You can maybe raise an issue.

Not sure what's the downvote for...

Downvoting without explanation is unfortunately common and it's often unclear, to say the least, why.

The axis x line=bottom is not ignored, as you can see when you choose a non-zero ymin (I find it clearest to just plot some data; this also avoids cluttering the options with ones that are irrelevant for your issue). The following image is created using the code below but without the fix.

The axis is at the bottom, it's just that the label position has not been reverted. If this is considered a bug, I do not know (there are several places in pgfplots where defaults are not restored by one option even though similar options changed those defaults; maybe it's a design principle) but I, too, find it surprising, so be sure to report it.
The fix is easy: Just make axis x line=bottom restore the default label position. I also added the corresponding fix for the y axis.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\pgfplotsset{
  axis x line/bottom/.append style={
    /pgfplots/every axis x label/.style={
      at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},
      anchor=near ticklabel,
    },
  },
  axis y line/left/.append style={
    /pgfplots/every axis y label/.style={
      at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},
      rotate=90,
      anchor=near ticklabel,
    },
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      axis y line=left,
      axis x line=center,
      axis x line=bottom,
      xlabel={xlabel},
      ylabel={ylabel},
      ]
    \addplot {x^3};                           
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Sorry for the late bounty award - I was confused by the website's HMI and thought that the bounty was alerady awarded.

@Dr.ManuelKuehner No worries. Awarding the bounty later keeps the question more visible, so some people do it on purpose. Once an answer is accepted it is set to receive the bounty automatically, so no answerer should get nervous. :-)
